# Лагает скролл в React приложении

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Появились фризы при прокрутке сайта на Пк, на мобильных устройствах всё нормально. Сайт ещё в процессе разработки. Подскажите, что может вызывать эти фризы?

Вот ссылка на репозиторий с сайтом: [ссылка](https://github.com/solodovnykov/Makoto-App)
Вот сайт залитый на хостинг: [ссылка](https://makoto-app.netlify.app/#/)

Comment: Вы пробовали сделать оптимизацию? В частности, при помощи React.lazy и withSuspense?

Comment: @Zhenyria суть в том что на сайте всего одна страница, там всё максимально просто. И я не понимаю почему фризы вообще могут возникать.

Comment: @Tobi чисто ради интереса кто пишет фронтовую часть?

Comment: @Tobi в коде есть приличная ошибка это после 3ех минут просмотра думаю и по этому фриз в компоненте navbar на 21 строке функция changeBackground

Comment: @Armen Добрый день, выяснил что лагает скролл из-за одно из компонентов, а именно ourServers. Сейчас разбираюсь с ним. Меня это удивило, ибо в этом компоненте ничего нет кроме вёрстки.

Comment: @Tobi Добрый я бы посоветовал сначала разобратся с той функцией о которой я говорил и если это не решит проблему тогда посмотрите компоненту

Comment: @Amen Благодарю за помощь, с компонентой разберусь обязательно, эта версия больше для тестов (учусь), в продакшн такое не пойдет. Выяснил что сайт тормозил из-за свойства blur, которые размывало изображение на заднем фоне. Раньше не сталкивался с такой проблемой.

Answer (score 1):

Лаги возникали из-за свойства filter: blur, которые размывало картинку на заднем фоне (в компоненте ourServers).